# Server-side Userinput Validation

Tags: javascript, sql, database, stored-procedures, sapui5

We work with SAP-Fiori / SAPUI5 / OpenUI5. Those frameworks are based on JS only. Due to manipulation issues on JS, we must not validate user inputs only via JS / through frontend. So a dev gave me the advice to verify and validate User Inputs (through form e.g.) via Stored Procedures.

Is this a good practice? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Frontendvalidation for immediately response to the user, backend for security. Like it has been since ever in the webdevelopment ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are checks which can be performed in the frontend and there are checks which can be performed in the backend.

frontend: You can do basic input validation, like zip count, if value is not langer than x digts. Or you can check that it is of the right type. You can filter out bad characters and so on.

backend: this is where you can check the pre-checked inputs against some data from backend systems, e.g. if the id of the user exists, authorization and so on.

So you can still do some frontend checks for basic input and security related things in the backend.

Comment: and how do we do that? i only know about frontend checks. where we are able to do backend checks w/o using stored procedures?

Comment: backend checks are performed when data is sent to your backend. So this depends on your backend technology. If you are using UI5 with Rest/Odata Services, you can have various backend technologies. So for example if your REST service is implemented in Java, you can implement a backend check logic to verify the data which was sent to the backend. If you have only stored procedures in the backend, your checking possibilities are surely more limited than if you would have e.g. Java as backend technology.